# Listing directory contents with unusual characters file names

Tags: php

The following code is for listing every file and folder of a directory in alphabetical order, and it works perfectly ... almost.

```
<?php
$files = array();
$dir = opendir('.');
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    if(($file != ".")and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")) {
    $files[] = $file;
    }   
}
natsort($files);
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo("<li><a href='$file'>$file</a>");
}
?>
```

The situation is that my files and folders have some strange characters in their names, like `é, ï, être.htm, écouter.txt`, etc. When I click on the links listed by the code above the links containing non Ascii characters lead to error 404 and the target is not opened, whereas the links with no strange characteres are fully operational.

Can you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: try ~url_encode($file)~ and quote it out properly.

Comment: Could you please explain me how to do that? I'm new to PHP.

Comment: I tried with « urlencode($file) » and now the links with special characters work, but not the ones with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  echo("<li><a href='".url_encode($file)."'>$file</a>");
```

You said that spaces were a problem but url_encode would've made the space a %20 so I'm not sure why you have an issue

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
`echo("<li><a href='".rawurlencode($file)."'>$file</a>");`
```

RFC 3986 - space replaced with `%20`

Comment: THE SOLUTION WITH **`rawurlencode($file)`** WORKS EVEN BETTER ‼ THE ADVANTAGE IS THAT IT'S A ONE STEP FUNCTION. THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself and thanks to «Forbs».

When extracting or getting the URL path of a file (**`$file`** in the code above) I followed two steps: The use of **`urlencode($file)`** and **`str_replace("+", "%20", $url)`**. The reason for this is that **`urlencode`** is perfect for changing unusual characters for the proper URL encoding, but this function also replaces the spaces in the URL path for a plus sign (+). Therefore, you need to use **`str_replace("+", "%20", $url)`** to replace every plus sign for the right URL encoding: **`%20`**.

So, here is the final PHP programming for listing the contents of a folder with unusual characters in file names (e.g. `être.txt, écouter.php, canción.mp3`).

**DIRECTORY LISTING**

```
<?php
$files = array();
$dir = opendir('.');
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php"))
    {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}
    natsort($files);
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $url_1 = urlencode($file);
        $url_2 = str_replace("+", "%20", $url_1);
        echo "<li><a href='".$url_2."'>".$file."</a></li>";
    }
?>
```

That's it. I hope it's of some use.